# Continuity of linear application between distribution spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, dual-spaces

First of all, I am aware there are many questions about this very topic, yet none of the answers is enough down to earth for me.

Let $\mathcal{D}'$ be the dual space of smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support and let $T : \mathcal{D}' \rightarrow \mathcal{D}'$ be the application given by the adjoint identity $\langle\phi, T \Lambda \rangle = \langle S \phi, \Lambda\rangle$, where $S$ is a continuous map $\mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$.

What does it mean that $T$ is continuous exactly?

I believe that sequential continuity should be equivalent to continuity, so if $\Lambda_n$ is a sequence of distribution converging to $0$, so that for any test function $\phi$ $\langle\phi, \Lambda_n\rangle \rightarrow \langle\phi, 0\rangle$ I get $\langle\phi, T \Lambda_n \rangle = \langle S \phi, \Lambda_n\rangle$, but since $\langle\phi, \Lambda_n\rangle$ converges to $0$ for any test function, isn't it true for $ S \phi$ making every linear map $T$ continuous?

Comment: It is not enough to check sequential continuity, since neither $\mathcal D$ nor $\mathcal D'$ are sequential spaces. However the adjoint of a continuous linear maps is always continuous in the weak* topology, you can use the same argument that you use - just replace the sequence with an arbitrary net.

Comment: Thanks @s.harp, may you elaborate on the fact that the adjoint of a continuous linear map is always w*-continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V,W$ be a topological vectorspace and let $V^*,W^*$ denote their dual spaces, ie the spaces of continuous linear maps $V\to\Bbb K$ resp. $W\to\Bbb K$. Suppose $T:V\to W$ is continuous and let $T^*: W^*\to V^*$ be its adjoint (continuity of $T$ is necessary for the *existence* of the adjoint).

If $w'_\alpha$ is some net in $W^*$, converging in weak* topology to $w'$, then for all $v\in V$:
$$\langle T^*  w'_\alpha, v\rangle = \langle w_\alpha', Tv\rangle \to \langle w',Tv\rangle = \langle T^*w',v\rangle.$$
Since this holds for all nets $v\in V$ you get that $T^*w_\alpha'$ converges in weak* topology to $T^*w'$. Since the convergent net was arbitrary you find $T^*$ is weak* continuous.

Comment: Thanks, this totally answers the question. Yet I'm a bit perplexed, since the issued popped up in my Functional Analysis course where we never mentioned nets; is it possible there's another (maybe more convoluted) way to prove this statement? I'm wondering about how to deal with continuity on $\mathcal{D}'$; when we talk about about $\mathcal{D}$ we resort to the continuity over $\mathcal{D}_{K}$ (where we have an explicit system of seminorms that generate the topology) for every compact set $K$...

Comment: The weak$^*$ topology on the dual $V^*$ is given by the directed family of seminorms $V^*\to [0,\infty)$, $\varphi\mapsto \max\{|\varphi(x)|: x\in E\}$ with finite subsets $E$ of $V$. You can then show the weak$^*$-continuity of $T^*$ by observing (in-) equalities for seminorms (a seminorm on the range $V^*$ gives a finite set $E$ and then $F=T(E)$ is a finite subset of $W$ which gives a seminorm on $W^*$...).